# Enable Bash-Completion to expand Superuser executables to full path

Tags: bash, opensuse, autocomplete

I'm running OpenSUSE 12.3 (and have seen the behavior since 11), and have found that I can't call Superuser programs (e.g. shutdown, reboot) without using the full path. For me, many of these executables live in `/sbin`, so instead of using `sudo reboot`, I have to call `sudo /sbin/reboot`. Thankfully, when using **sudo** OpenSUSE's shell (**bash**) will expand these paths when I press the `Tab` key, so `sudo rebo[Tab]` will result in `sudo /sbin/reboot`.

OpenSUSE provides a package by the name of **bash-completion** which expands the auto-complete functionality of **bash** to include all sorts of other contexts (e.g. **gsettings**). Unfortunately, by default, this package does not expand the Superuser executables to their full paths, but just expands the executable name, so `sudo rebo[Tab]` will result in `sudo reboot`, which will lead to a `sudo: reboot: command not found` error.

How do I install/run **bash-completion** yet ensure the autocomplete for Superuser executables expands to the full path?

Comment: That's a problem with your sudo configuration. Normally sudo does add the sbin directories to the search path.

Comment: I think the SUSE developers might disagree that this constitutes a *problem*, since the expansion to a full path clearly indicates that the developers have done this by design. I am just asking the question whether **bash-completion** can mimic this behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expanding [@Gilles](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/88468/13308#comment132227_88468)'s comment to an answer:

This question asked about **bash-completion** expanding `/sbin` executables to their full paths on Tab, but I have satisfied my requirements by adding the Superuser directories (e.g. `/sbin`, `/usr/sbin`, etc.) to the **sudo** search path.

To do this, I had to add the `secure_path` variable to the Sudoers file (edit with `visudo`), something like the following line:

```
Defaults    secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
```

If someone provides a solution to actually expand the path of these executables, I would consider that the true answer to the question, but again, this solution satisfies my requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just add /sbin to PATH var?:
`export PATH=$PATH:/sbin`